Why can't I make my packaged code not namespace-agnostic?
For my company, I created this Open-Source app to showcase Agentic AI in Salesforce before Copilots and Agentforce came out. To make it easily installable as Unlocked Package in several orgs we decided to give it a namespace aquiva_os.
I had hoped the namespace is only relevant upon creating packages and package versions and HAS NOT to be hard coded in any of the code and low-code files. But when trying to push (instead of installing a version) the code to an org, I realized the namespace had sneaked into some files.
Is there a way to get rid of this or do some files in Salesforce still require a hardcoded namespace? I remember that the plan was to keep package metadata namespace agnostic.
The files where the namespace has sneaked in are:

Named Credential calls
EmpApi channels in LWC
External CredentialPrincipal XML


Sadly, several metadata types do require the namespace prefix for various references (a couple of common examples are Aura components and Flows). I think you are stuck with suggesting a string replacement before deploying the code without packaging, or make an unlocked package with no namespace (which is what we landed on for the convenience of gaining test coverage isolated from the production environment). Instead of namespacing, we prefixed all metadata API names to help avoid name clashes.

Thanks @PhilW would you mind converting this helpful comment to an answer?

Sadly, several metadata types do require the namespace prefix for various references (common ones are Aura components and Flows, for example).
I think you are stuck with either:

Suggesting a string replacement before deploying the code, "from source" and without packaging, or
Making an unlocked package with no namespace.

When faced with similar issues, we chose to do the latter. This also has the benefit that tests run (with coverage measurement) during the package version creation process, and so in a clean "packaging org". Thus the tests are not interfered with by any "customization" (e.g. extra validation rules that break test data factories) applied on top in the subscriber/Production environment. The package's tests are not run on the subscriber environment.
NB: When we took the no-namespace approach, instead of namespacing, we prefixed all metadata API names to help avoid name clashes.
